# Why I don't get floating point number when i divide (float) number by (float) number?

Tags: c++, function, floating-point

I had a function (money) needs two parameters (salary, days)
every week there are 2 holidays so working days = days - (weeks * 2)
you only spend money on working days
i want to calculate how much money do you spend per day
so i did --> salary / working days = sometimes this must equal floating point number but i don't get it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int money(float salary, int days)
{
    // every week you have 2 days off
    // you only spend money on working days
    float workingdays = days - ( (days / 7) * 2 );
    return salary / workingdays; 
}

int main()
{
    cout << money(2015, 21) << "\n"; // 134.333
    cout << money(4500, 40) << "\n"; // 150
    return 0;
}
```

in the first call i need the function money to return 134.33333333 but it returns 134
why??

Comment: What do you think `int money(...` means? If you want a float then write `float money(...`.

Comment: Incidentally, floating-point is generally not used for money calculations (what coins do you use to pay someone $134.33333333?). Typically an application uses an integer type to keep track of cents (or whatever the coin with the smallest value is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the money function you are returning int so the function return int value .Modify int with float , then your money function return float value

`

```
float money(float salary, int days){
    float workingdays = days - ( (days / 7) * 2 );
    return salary / workingdays;
}
```

Comment: N.B. `workingdays` will always hold an integer value, since `days/7` is an integer division (and the other operations don't change that). It may or may not be what OP expects ...

Answer (score 2):

You've declared `money` to return an `int`, so the result of the division will be converted to `int`.  With two `float` operands, the division will produce `float` result. However, since this is used in a `return` statement for a function returning `int`, the `float` result will be converted to `int`. That conversion truncates (rounds toward zero) to an integer value to be returned.

Comment: Consider discussing whether `( (days / 7) * 2 )` is really what OP wants. Maybe `( (days / 7.0) * 2 )` is closer, for similar reasons. Or `( (days * 2) / 7 )`. Though the satisfaction with 150 indicates that they are happy with their code there.

Comment: @Yunnosch: `days / 7` is obviously a way to obtain the number of whole weeks. (Though this computation of `workingdays` is wrong.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Exactly. OP seems happy, but I wonder whether they should be...

Comment: The OP's question was answered, that's it. Let him come back when he discovers the other bugs.

Comment: Re “When you do a division, if either operand is a `float` or `double`, both operands will be converted to `double` and the division will occur as a `double`”:  Division performs the *usual arithmetic conversions*. These do not convert two `float` operands to `double`. If both operands are `float`, then `float` is used.